# Create autogenerated column from other table in PosgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have two tables: **postavka** and **detail**. I need to add an autogenerated column to **postavka** which is generated from multiplying `postavka.count` on `detail.price` (detail selected by **detail** field in **postavka**).

I created script `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.postavka ADD COLUMN total_price double precision GENERATED ALWAYS AS (postavka.count * (select price from detail where (postavka.detail == detail.id)) STORED;` but it is incorrect. How I must change this to be valid?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GENERATED` columns can only refer to other columns of the same table, so it is not relevant in your case.

You can do the job with a trigger function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_update_postavka() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT NEW.count * price
    INTO NEW.total_price
    FROM detail
   WHERE id = NEW.detail ;
  RETURN NEW ;
END ; $$
    
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_insert_update_postavka BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON postavka
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION before_insert_update_postavka() ;
```